# laravel cashier stripe - How charge customer immediately when changing subscription with the same interval

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I implemented laravel 5.2 with cashier (stripe).
I have three plan:

1. Basic - monthly
2. Pro - monthly
3. Agency - monthly

Now if I have customer that subscribe to Basic plan and he decided to subscribe to Pro plan. How can I charge him immediately with cashier?

From Stripe I got the answer that

> if customer was in Basic plan and subscribe to Pro plan than hi will
>   charge in the next charge day. but if he subscribe to a plan with a
>   different interval (annually instead monthly) he will charge
>   immediately.

How I can handle this bizarre situation?

Let's say the customer subscribe to a basic plan (the chipper one) paid it's first month, and day after change to Agency plan (much more expensive) and then he cancelled is credit-card. He will enjoy almost a month if Agency plan while he only pays for the Basic plan, and at the next charge day... he won't be charged because his credit-card was cancelled.

Comment: Not certain whether this is an issue/oddity with Cashier or Stripe itself. You can always create one-off charges with Stripe and Cashier if you're willing to do some calculations for dates and plan prices.